# Cauchy sequence with $\{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ not closed converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Suppose $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence and $A = \{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ not closed.  Show that there exists $x \in X$ such that $x_n \longrightarrow x$.

Since $A$ is not closed:
$$
\forall  y\in A , \exists \varepsilon > 0 s.t. S(y,\varepsilon) \subset A
$$
and since $x_n$ is Cauchy:
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0 ,\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} s.t. \forall n,m \geq n_0 : \rho (x_n,x_m) < \varepsilon
$$
But I can't see a way to connect these two to prove convergence. Some starting hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $X$ ? Where the $x_n$ are from ?

Comment: ... and what's $S(y,\varepsilon)$?

Comment: $X$ is a metric space and $S(y, \varepsilon)$ is an open sphere with center $y$ and radius $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $x\in\overline{\{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}}\setminus\{x_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}$. Then there is some sequence of terms of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converging to $x$. In other words (since $x$ itself does not belong to the sequence), $x$ is the limit of some subsequence of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. But whenever a Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence, the whole sequence converges to the limit of that subsequence.

Comment: +1. A quick answer.

Comment: Why the fact that $x$ does not belong to the sequence ensures that it's the limit of some subsequence of $x_n$?

Comment: There is a sequence $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k}=x$. Is it possible that the set $\{n_k\,|\,k\in\mathbb N\}$ is finite? No, because then there would be a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n_k=N$ infinitely many times and we would have to have $x_N=x$. But $x$ does not belong to the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Not closed means there is a sequence from the set which converges to a point not in the set. Let $(y_n)$ be a sequence from $\{x_n:n 
\geq 1\}$ such that $y_n \to y$ and $y\neq x_n$ for any $n$. For each $n$ we can write $y_n=x_{k_n}$ and this sequence  cannot be equal to $x$ after some stage because $y\neq x_n$ for any $n$. Hence we can find a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ which is convergent. It is  well known fact that if a subsequence of a Cauchy sequence converges then the whole sequence converges.